ESLint (TypeScript) with forwardRef: 'badgeContent' Prop Missing in PropTypes Validation (react/prop-types)
I encountered an ESLint warning in a component that uses forwardRef, which seemed odd. Even though I'm using TypeScript, ESLint keeps showing the following error for missing props validation:
'badgeContent' is missing in props validation eslintreact/prop-types
And this happens for every type-defined prop.
Here's the original code:
export interface EditableCarouselItemProps
  extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  imgSrc?: string;
  title?: string;
  description?: string;
  badgeContent?: ReactNode;
  onDeleteItemClick?: IconButtonProps["onClick"];
}

const EditableCarouselItem = forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  EditableCarouselItemProps
>((props, ref) => {
  const {
    badgeContent,
    title,
    description,
    imgSrc,
    onDeleteItemClick,
    ...other
  } = props;
  ...

Usually, these errors occur when I forget to define prop types, but I confirmed the interface was correctly defined. After searching for a solution and even trying ChatGPT, nothing worked. Eventually, I found a fix:
Instead of extending an interface, I switched to using a type with intersection:

type EditableCarouselItemProps = HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & {
  imgSrc?: string;
  title?: string;
  description?: string;
  badgeContent?: ReactNode;
  onDeleteItemClick?: IconButtonProps["onClick"];
};

const EditableCarouselItem = forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  EditableCarouselItemProps
>((props, ref) => {
  const {
    badgeContent,
    title,
    description,
    imgSrc,
    onDeleteItemClick,
    ...other
  } = props;

This resolved the issue for me, but I'm still not sure why using type with intersection works when extending interfaces didn't. Can someone explain why this happens?
I tried adding an interface to my props, but the error persisted. I also attempted to separate my original component from the forwardRef component, but the same error kept occurring.
